# No power in 2 rooms what could it be

Tags: electrical

Tv was on in a room power went off and now there isn’t any power in 2 rooms. Breaker didn’t flip. My husband has checked all the power outlets in both rooms, changed out a few of them but still no power. What could it be?

Comment: Sometimes tripped breakers aren't obvious. Have you tried turning it off and then back on again?

Comment: Power goes from the breaker to the first outlet then to next then to next.  If any wire is broken or loose along that path, then no power beyond that point.  Wires that use the the push in connections in the back instead of the screws are known for this problem.

Comment: Breaker in a different panel?  Are you very familiar with the entire building?

Comment: Also check to make sure those circuits weren't fed from a GFCI outlet that tripped it's ground fault protection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Circuit breaker was fine. There’s only 1 breaker box outside.

Comment: The whole second floor is on that circuit but only 2 room’s don’t have power.

Comment: Yes, check for a tripped GFCI outlet/deadfront.  They can be located in the oddest places.  For example, the GFCI that controls the outlets in my garage is located in the closet of my basement bathroom.

Comment: We don’t have GFCI outlets in the rooms. Only the bathrooms and kitchen have one.

Comment: This indicates a failed connection. This could be in the hot conductor or the neutral conductor. Use a plug in circuit tester to identify which receptacles on the circuit are working and which are not. This should tell you whether the failed connection is in the hot or the neutral  Try to determine which of receptacles that are out is closest to the panel. The fault can be in the working receptacle that is just closer to the panel than the first receptacle which is not currently working. If your receptacles are  connected via spring backstabs, this is a common problem.

Comment: If you don't have a circuit tester you could use a plug-in lamp or other small appliance, even a hair dryer (use low setting) to find out which receptacles are working and which are not, but it won't tell you whether the fault is in the hot or the neutral.

Comment: A non-contact voltage tester is a convenient and safe way to look for a fault in the hot connections.

Comment: We called an electrician. Thank you for all your help.